# MarkdownDeep AutoHeadingIDs are not working

Tags: c#, markdowndeep

I'm working with [MarkdownDeep](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/) in my WebSite:

```
public static MvcHtmlString FromMarkdown(this HtmlHelper helper, string value)
{
    var md = new Markdown
    {
        ExtraMode = true,
        SafeMode = true,
        NewWindowForExternalLinks = true,
        MarkdownInHtml = true,
        AutoHeadingIDs = true
    };

    text = md.Transform(value);

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(text);
}
```

My problem here is, that headings still not get IDs since I want to work with anchors. 
Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you can't use property `SafeMode` together with `AutoHeadingIDs`. It's not documented but it solved my problem. Initialization now looks:

```
var md = new Markdown
{
    ExtraMode = true,
    NewWindowForExternalLinks = true,
    MarkdownInHtml = true,
    AutoHeadingIDs = true
};
```